# Argument labels before parameters in functions - possible bug in Swift Markup?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I have the following function in a class:

```
/// Returns the weather conditions at the given location.
/// - parameter for: A location on the Earth's surface.
/// - returns: If found, the `WeatherConditions` at the supplied location otherwise nil.
public func conditions(for location: Location) -> WeatherConditions? {
    return nil  // The actual code is not important to the question.
}
```

which is called as follows `let myWeather = conditions(for: myLocation)`.

The code works fine, the question is about the documentation.  The image below is what is seen in the 'quick help' window for the `conditions` function.  Given that the user of the function must use the external argument label (`for`) and also that I have explicitly documented that label, shouldn't the parameters line in the quick help window read `Parameters for` and not `Parameters location`?

Is this a bug in Xcode or is there a reason the (internal) parameter name is displayed and not the external argument label?

[image]

Comment: I always found that a little strange, but my guess is that the "external parameter name" acts as a *label* for the call site and the "internal parameter name" as the actual *name*. The label is supposed to make the function call read a bit like a sentence or phrase. In Swift 3 conventions, these labels are regularly prepositions instead of nouns, and it'd make sense to describe parameters by their name (typically a noun) instead of a label (which can be a preposition). If my guess is right, I'd prefer —for clarity— they'd use "label" and "name" instead of "external" and "internal" name.

Comment: XCode should really be able to produce two version of the documentation. One for the consumers of the API without access to the source code, showing the external name only in the declaration line and using the external name for the parameter description. And another one for the implementor of the method, showing both names in the declaration and using the internal name in the parameter description. I don't think XCode can distinguish these two views yet.

Comment: @Codo I'm inclined to agree but doubt it would ever happen.  Meanwhile, I've raised this as a bug (27921906).  I'll update here with any response.

Comment: I also mainly see it as a bug. If XCode doesn't provide both an internal and external view, it should show the external view, thus only use the parameter name *for* in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, `for` is not the parameter; `location` is. And quick help is documenting parameters.

Preferring that quick help identify `for` as a location on the Earth's surface, as has been suggested, would be a bit puzzling to the reader.

The [SPLG](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) and [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) use the terminology "parameter" and "argument label" (as in your question title) instead of "internal parameter" and "external parameter" (which may lead to the confusion you're raising). Given this, parameters fall under the Parameters heading in quick help, and argument labels appear in the Declaration.

Answer (score 0):

the "for" word is not mandatory word, it is optional for better understanding of the code, when used.

In the Swift 3 book stands:

> The use of argument labels can allow a **function to be called** in an expressive, **sentence-like manner**, while still providing a function body that is **readable and clear in intent**.

Without this word, writing the code would be

```
let myWeather = conditions(myLocation)
```

When we define methods, it is always fine to use words like with:, using:, for:, withLabel: etc.

Comment: I guess Vince O'Sullivan wants to fix the documentation and not change the signature of his method. This doesn't really answer it.

Comment: But I don't understand why would we replace the word "location" in the documentation for the word "for". If it is parameter, it should represent the word, that we use in the code as a variable, doesn't it?

Comment: He asked "shouldn't the parameters line in the quick help window read Parameters for and not Parameters location", so that's why I put the answer with argument label stuff.

Comment: Even if the label can be and is omitted in the call, the parameter still requires a name in the documentation. For the callers of the method, the first name applies, i.e. *for* in this case. That's what one would expect in the documentation. The second name (*location* in this case), is the internal name used by the implementation of the method. It should be hidden for consumers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the documentation to show for, then you need to show in comments as:

```
/// Returns the weather conditions at the given location.
/// - parameter `for Location`: A location on the Earth's surface.
/// - returns: If found, the `WeatherConditions` at the supplied location otherwise nil.
public func conditions(for location: CLLocation) -> AnyObject? {
    return nil  // The actual code is not important to the question.
}
```

[image]

Comment: Under parameters is says "No description", the internal name *location* is visible twice and the parameter description now appears as a bullet point of the general descriptions. That's even worse than the original output and certainly not what Vince O'Sullivan was looking for.

Comment: Because the description bullet uses the label+parameter compound, and the parameter section describes location only... I don't know... for me the documentation is clear.